# Read phone number along with address using Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contact-mimetype

I want to read contact info from build contact picker. I am reading phone number,street,email and address.It's coming wrong.

Following is the code to **invoke contact picker**:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
context.startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, REQUEST_ID_CONTACT_PICKER);
```

Following is the `OnActivityResult` method's code, where i am `fetching contact` info from cursor:

```
Uri contactURI = intent.getData();
                    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contactURI, null, null, null, null);
int count = cursor.getCount();
// here value of count is 1, so need to do cursor.moveToNext() to go to selected record.
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String givenName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String familyName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            String displayName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String middleName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));

            int contactType = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            String phoneNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String poBox = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
            String street = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
            String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
            String state = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
            String postalCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
            String country = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
            String neighborhood = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD));
            String formattedAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
            String emailId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

        }
```

I am unable to identify, why i am getting wrong data (i.e. contact number) in street, emailId etc column.

> Here cursor.moveToNext() is required to go to first row, so it's
>   obviously required, and my question is not that i am getting different
>   record, i am getting mobile number in street, emailId column, which is
>   wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After wasting more than 3 days found the way to do what i wanted:

**There's a [common structure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) for storing all type of data i.e phone, address, email etc.
[See the common columns names](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html),**

> That's why we can not get all type of data (contact, email, address
>   etc) with contact picker intent, so first we need to get the contact
>   Id or contact lookUpKey as a result of contact picker intent, than we
>   need to query other details separately.
>
> But the problem comes when try to fetch other details because, each
>   data is saved in same table structure, i.e. generic table that can
>   hold any kind of contact data.
>
> And the kind of data stored in a given row is specified by the row's
>   MIMETYPE value, which determines the meaning of the generic columns
>   DATA1 through DATA15. For example, if the data Mime type is
>   Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, then the column DATA1 stores the phone
>   number, but if the data Mime type is Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, then
>   DATA1 stores the email address.
>
> So first we need to set where clause with Mime type before querying
>   the any type of content, see the list of mime types [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html)

This is how we should fire a intent to choose the contact:

```
int REQUEST_ID_CONTACT_PICKER = 1001;
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, REQUEST_ID_CONTACT_PICKER);
```

Than in onActivityResult, we get the URI in data:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Contact contact = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ID_CONTACT_PICKER :
          try {
            Uri contactURI = intent.getData();
            contact = fetchAndBuildContact(getApplicationContext(), contactURI);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Pick contact sucessfully!!"+contact.toString());
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to pick contact!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          break;
      }
    } else {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to pick contact!!");
    }
  }
```

Not we need to find the LookUpKey, which is helpful to fetch any Mime type of data:

```
  private Contact fetchAndBuildContact(Context ctx, Uri uriContact){
      // Getting cursorLookUpKey because contacts ID may not be correct all the time.
      Cursor cursorLookUpKey = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uriContact, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY}, null, null, null);
      Contact contact = null;
      String lookupKey = null;
      if (cursorLookUpKey.moveToFirst()) {
          lookupKey = cursorLookUpKey.getString(cursorLookUpKey.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY));
          if(null != lookupKey ){
              contact = new Contact();
              contact = buildConactPhoneDetails(lookupKey, ctx, contact);
              contact = buildEmailDetails(lookupKey, ctx, contact);
              contact = buildAddressDetails(lookupKey, ctx, contact);
          }
      }
      cursorLookUpKey.close();
      return contact;
  }
```

This is how we can fetch Phone Details using `ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`:

```
private Contact buildConactPhoneDetails(String lookupKey, Context ctx, final Contact contact) {
      ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
      String contactWhere = ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
      String[] contactWhereParams = new String[]{lookupKey, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
      Cursor cursorPhone = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, contactWhere, contactWhereParams, null);
      if (cursorPhone.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursorPhone.moveToNext()) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    String givenName = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String familyName = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                    String middleName = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
                    int contactType = cursorPhone.getInt(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    String phoneNo = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    contact.contactNumber = phoneNo;
                    contact.givenName = givenName;
                    contact.familyName = familyName;
                    contact.middleName = middleName;
                    contact.contactType = contactType;
                }
            }
      }
      cursorPhone.close();
      return contact;
  }
```

This is how we can fetch Email Details using `ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`:

```
  private Contact buildEmailDetails (String lookupKey, Context ctx, final Contact contact) {
      ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
      String emailWhere = ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY+ " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
      String[] emailWhereParams = new String[]{lookupKey, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
      Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, emailWhere, emailWhereParams, null); 
      if (emailCursor.moveToNext()) { 
          String emailId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
          contact.emailId = emailId;
      } 
      emailCursor.close();
      return contact;
  }
```

This is how we can fetch PhoneDetails using `ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`:

```
  private Contact buildAddressDetails(String lookupKey, Context ctx, final Contact contact) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
    String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
    String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{lookupKey, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
    Cursor addrCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null); 
    if (addrCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String poBox = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
        String street = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
        String city = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
        String state = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
        String postalCode = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
        String country = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
        String neighborhood = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.NEIGHBORHOOD));
        String formattedAddress = addrCursor.getString(addrCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));

        contact.poBox = poBox;
        contact.street = street;
        contact.city = city;
        contact.state = state;
        contact.zipcode = postalCode;
        contact.country = country;
        contact.street = street;
        contact.neighborhood = neighborhood;
        contact.poBox = poBox;
        contact.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
    }
    addrCursor.close();
    return contact;
  }
```

And this is the Contact POJO class, we are creating in above code:

```
public class Contact {
    String country;
    String poBox;
    String givenName;
    String middleName;
    String familyName;
    String address;
    String city;
    String state;
    String street;
    String zipcode;
    String emailId;
    String contactNumber;
    String neighborhood;
    String formattedAddress;
    String label;
    int contactType;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice piece of code, thanks for sharing! Deserves much more upvotes.

Comment: Best Answer :) Thanks